# Get the max value of axis in a KDE plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, probability-density

After some processing done to my dataframe, I ended up with the following df (I did `final_df.to_csv()` and this is that saved file:

```
kilometers
1072.1995482049733
2503.2499069986962
354.0418359911766
858.2197121707121
872.7067362778436
1110.8656962113155
1956.1799725414431
298.5388710676759
933.9980032255144
844.663104277453
```

Therefore, if I want to get the probability density function (pdf) I use [`pandas.dataframe.plot.kde`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.kde.html) to obtain the following plot:

```
ploti = final_df.plot.kde()
ploti
```

[image: kde plot]

And getting the pdf and plotting it:

```
from scipy import stats
import seaborn as sns

data = final_df['kilometers']
loc = data.mean()
scale = data.std()
pdf = stats.norm.pdf(data, loc=loc, scale=scale)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = sns.lineplot(x=data, y=pdf, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

[image: PDF]

**Now to my question:** Is there a way to obtain the highest value (where max is) (let's say x and y, although just x is fine) of these plots? I've been checking in [getting values on x axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31476839/find-a-value-from-x-axis-that-correspond-to-y-axis-in-matplotlib-python) and some matplotlib documentation ([about axis in here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/axis_api.html)). I tried some `ax.get_children()` ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24153278/how-to-get-output-of-pandas-plotkind-kde)) but without any use. The data should be in x and y axis (IN THEORY, to my understanding, but it might just refer to what the plot phisically has, not the data): Following the latter question referenced in here:

```
ploti.get_children()

[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7fd294de1c60>,
 <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x7fd294b18040>,
 <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x7fd294b18400>,
 <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x7fd294b18460>,
 <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x7fd294b18490>,
 <matplotlib.axis.XAxis at 0x7fd294b18070>,
 <matplotlib.axis.YAxis at 0x7fd294b18bb0>,
 Text(0.5, 1.0, ''),
 Text(0.0, 1.0, ''),
 Text(1.0, 1.0, ''),
 <matplotlib.legend.Legend at 0x7fd294de16f0>,
 <matplotlib.patches.Rectangle at 0x7fd294b1b280>]

ploti.get_children()[5] #this one should have what I'm looking for

<matplotlib.axis.XAxis at 0x7fd294b18070>

ploti.get_children()[5]._x

AttributeError: 'XAxis' object has no attribute '_x'
```

I thought: hey, maybe check what attributes this object has, so maybe there is some 'get_x_value'. But I coulnd't find anything relevant to what I'm looking for (I might lack knowledge also):

```
dir(ploti.get_children()[5])
```

(I could post the output but it's quite long and verbose. Feel free to ask for it! )

Apart from what I think I could be using: numpy converting all values of the plot and getting the max value of an axis; Is there a quick way to obtain the max value of an axis in a plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get data with:

```
data = ax.lines[0].get_xydata()
```

Then get the coordinates for the maximum y with `np.where`:

```
data[np.where(data[:, 1] == max(data[:, 1]))]
```

Comment: Neat answer, thanks! The first line works perfectly to get all the data. I did a test for the max value with your oneliner and a simple `for i in data:` and update a max value `if i[1]> max_val` , and I get two different results. Is yours correct or am I going wrong? `Oneliner max value = [[1.07219955e+03 5.90961697e-04]] 
x = 1072.199548204973 
Looping max value = [1.11086570e+03 5.90407005e-04]
x = 1110.8656962113157 `

Comment: Note that max value above has shape `(1,2)`. So you need to compare it like that `if i[1]> max_val[0][1]`. This doesn't change max_val in my case

Comment: `max_val` in the `if` condition is just a variable initialised to `0`, to get a max value of a list in this case! the Oneliner Max Val is the printing of the second line in your answer, and then `[0][1]` of your answer! I think you will be able to see it in [here temporarily](https://codeshare.io/3AJE3B)

Comment: The problem is you should start with `where_in_data = -1` as you already increase it after each inside if loop https://codeshare.io/3AJE3B

Comment: OH! I see, if not `-1`, it's taking the next value, because it starts in `0`. And my stupid brain did not compare the `Y `values of both, where it can be seen that the oneliner is the highest (physically) in the graph. Thanks a lot!